# How do you run webdriver io tests for different browsers in a loop?

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

The following script works, however, it appears that when an error occurs in one test, it will cause all the other ones to fail as well. How do you make it so that they will run independently of each other?

```
var combos = [
['Windows 7', 'firefox'],
['Windows 7', 'chrome'],
['Windows 7', 'iexplore'],
['Windows 7', 'opera'],
['Windows 8', 'firefox'],
['Windows 8', 'chrome'],
['Windows 8', 'iexplore'],
['Windows 8', 'opera']
];

combos.forEach(function(currentValue) {
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: currentValue[1],
        platform: currentValue[0]
    },
    host: 'ondemand.saucelabs.com',
    port: 80,
    user: [redacted],
    key: [redacted],
    logLevel: "verbose"
};

    var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
    var client = webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://google.com')
    ...

});
```

Comment: You might want to try looking at the new  [multiremote](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html) function that was added in Webdriverio v3

Comment: multiremote is not intended for parallel testing. Please check out the new wdio test runner http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html . It allows you do specify capabilities as an array. They will get executed in parallel then

Answer (score 1):

Adding Try-Catch to your test should solve this:

```
try {
    var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
    var client = webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://google.com')
    ...
}
catch(err) {
    //log the error
}
```